# On Hovering an element,make another element appear

Tags: html, css

```css
.LinkBar {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 140px;
  height: 37px;
  border: 1px solid #c02c3a;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  background-color: #c02c3a;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 9px;
  color: white;
}

div.SampleMenu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 140px;
  background-color: Grey;
  margin-left: 300.5px;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

div.SampleMenu ul li {
  color: White;
  padding: 0;
  display: none;
}

div.SampleMenu ul li a {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: large;
  text-align: center;
}

#HeaderBar:hover+.SampleMenu ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="CentralHeader">
  <div class="LinkBar" id="HeaderBar">All</div>
  <div class="SampleMenu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#Movies">Movies</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Events">Events</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Sports">Sports</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Plays">Plays</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above segment,I try to manipulate a user-drop down while an element 
is hovered,but the drop down disappears as the cursor is moved towards 
drop down. I  want to select an item in drop down which needs drop down to 
appear even on moving cursor from the specified element.How can I achieve 
this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have applied `display:block` code to `#HeaderBar` hover and when your cursor goes to dropdown the hover code does not run.

So apply `display:block` on `.SampleMenu ul:hover` as well

```
#HeaderBar:hover+.SampleMenu ul,
.SampleMenu ul:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

And also apply `display:none` to the `.SampleMenu ul` not each li elements of it.

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.LinkBar {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 140px;
  height: 37px;
  border: 1px solid #c02c3a;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  background-color: #c02c3a;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 9px;
  color: white;
}

div.SampleMenu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 140px;
  background-color: Grey;
  margin-left: 300.5px;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 0px;
  display: none;
  border-top: 2px solid #fff;
}

div.SampleMenu ul li {
  color: White;
  padding: 0;
}

div.SampleMenu ul li a {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: large;
  text-align: center;
}

#HeaderBar:hover+.SampleMenu ul,
.SampleMenu ul:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="CentralHeader">
  <div class="LinkBar" id="HeaderBar">All</div>
  <div class="SampleMenu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#Movies">Movies</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Events">Events</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Sports">Sports</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Plays">Plays</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works fine seperately..But as a part of module,code does not reflect the change..:(

Comment: @GunacelanM what issue is coming..?

Comment: @GunacelanM on  `#HeaderBar` hover its working or not...?

Comment: @GunacelanM have you changed the your css to mine...?

Comment: On #HeaderBar  hover,dropdown shows up but when the focus is out of it ,dropdown disappears as before

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163969/discussion-between-bhuwan-bhatt-and-gunacelan-m).